# Do motors need to have capacitor even if being used with motor shield

Tags: motor

I'm using a 12V DC geared motor with an Adafruit motor shield which is connected to Arduino.

So, I want to know inspite of using the motor shield, do I need to add capacitors to the motor?

Comment: You should connect the shield as Adafruit prescribes. In what way do you think you need capacitors?

Comment: Post a schematic of how you think extra capacitors should be added, a description of what you think they'll do, and what you think the problem with what the shield documentation suggests (not necessarily in that order), and then we can comment.

Comment: lots of motor shields have that sort of thing (dioides too) built-in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the motors have a lot of "brush noise" you need to add capacitors to the motor. It is written in the [FAQ](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-motor-shield/faq#faq-21).

The noise must be suppressed at the source or the motor leads will act like antennae and broadcast it to the rest of the system [link](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-motor-shield/faq#faq-24).